# Informing Googlebot for deprecated pages

Tags: googlebot, search-results

I publish timetables in my website.
For example last year I published `Number 2 bus Summer 2013 timetable`.
I has pretty good ranking on Google SERPs for `number 2 bus timetable`

But this year I added a new page with the name "Number 2 bus Summer 2014 timetable".
When users search `number 2 bus timetable` in Google, they find 2013 timetable in first page of SERPs. But I want them to find 2014 timetable.

Thy can reach 2014 page with the keywords `number 2 bus timetable 2014`. But most of the users doesn't write year name.

So what's the proper way to say Googlebot that 2013 page is deprecated and newer version is 2014 page ?

I created a link from 2013 page to 2013 page and added a deprecation alert for visitors. But I still see 2013 timetable in first page of Google SERPs.

Of course it is possible to 301 redirect, 2013 page to 2014 page. But I want users to reach old pages to compare the differences between years.

(As you would guess I have many pages like this.)

Edit:
Why I don't put timetables on same page and show different years' timetables with sorting. Because my old pages has good pagerank scores or SERPs. Removing these old page will remove them.

Answer (score 4):

I would really have one main URL, which would show the calendar for the current year. If you do not currently have year encoded in your current top ranking page, then use just that one. Now on this page you can provide additional links to either calendars of previous years or have some sort of functionality to let users compare / see calendars from different years on the same page.

Also, optionally, in all the pages containing calendars for previous years, add the message on top that this is archived calendar with a link to the current one.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking the 2013 and any other previous page out of the index by using:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Or by blocking access to using your robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /schedules/bus-schedule-2013.html
```

Of course this would be the fastest and surest way but may also be too draconian for your like.

Another possibility is that all of the bus schedules are in fact one single page where someone can use some sort of selection mechanism to chose the year, but it defaults to this year. That could be as simple as a single page with several years listed, or something that requires a bit of programming.

Comment: but this tag will completely remove that page from Google, but the OP don't want to drop that page from google, he mentioned that the old page is useful for users to compare the results with previous year.

Comment: @Bala: The OP doesn't actually say they "don't want to drop that page from google" - they just want the old version to still be available on the site.

Comment: @Bala From the question it sounded to me like that the user wanted people to find 2014 and not 2013 in the SERPs. With little to no control over SERPs, there are only a few options and some are not pretty. I also added another thought where the indexed page / landing page was a mechanism that could select any year the user wants. That is a fair option that may be technically easy to implement. Since I was not sure what the user wanted, I covered my bases with two basic options. I am sure a better answer will come along! ;-)